# Ubuntu 18.04: vue command not found

Tags: 18.04

When I run:

```
vue --version
```

I get this error message:

```
Command 'vue' not found, did you mean:

  command 'vpe' from deb texlive-latex-extra

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Notes:

```
npm config get prefix
/home/begueradj/.nvm/versions/node/v12.8.0
```

and:

```
npm list vue
/home/begueradj
└── vue@2.6.10
```

I previously run:

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
yarn global add @vue/cli-service-global
```

How to fix this ?

For the moment, when I add this to `~/.profile`

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

and run: `source ~/.profile`

The issue is solved ... but only for the current Terminal session (I had to run `source .profile` each time I open a new Terminal session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

I had to add permanently the variable mentioned indirectly above (`.yarn/bin`) to **/etc/environment**:

`:/.yarn/bin`

I then restarted my laptop and got it work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 22, I fixed the issue as shown below.

Check yarn global bin path using `yarn global bin`
this should show an output similar to
`/home/username/.yarn/bin`

Add this export command to your `~/.profile`

```
export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"
```

Reload the profile using

```
source ~/.profile
```

Finally

```
vue --version
```

Comment: I did not try it, but makes sense to me. Useful feedback. Thank you.